# what is the best project to introduce among 'Google oauth2.0 java client' and 'java-scribe' to provide user logins for facebook/twitter?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I am trying to provide additional login mechanisms for our web applications. Currently, it is using the Google accounts login.  I want users to login using facebook/twitter etc.
After searching the group and on the stack overflow, I am thinking, that you can do in the following ways
- Google oauth2.0 java client (https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth2).  An example of using the DailyMotion oauth2.0 using this jars is found here. 
- Use java-scribe. An example is found here https://code.google.com/p/gwtoauthlogindemo/ and here

Any suggestions, what should I choose going forward?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at Google Identity Toolkit - this offers more than just Google Accounts:
https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/

Comment: Thanks for your reply aeijdenberg. But that is available for limited number of Trusted Testers.

Comment: If it looks interesting to you, there's a link on there to "Request an invitation" which is a short form to fill out - that team is usually pretty responsive.